# Draw curved arrow in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, shapes

I want to draw a curved right arrow at TCanvas as shape in Microsoft Word.
Does anybody know an working method?

[image]

Comment: Draw two circles, rectangle and a triangle. This is simple geometrical task.

Comment: @Ari0nhh what do you need a rectangle for? White background?

Comment: @dummzeuch To cut off bigger circle bottom.

Comment: What do you mean by "in microsoft word"?

Comment: i mean curved right arrow like shapes in Microsoft word

Answer (score 6):

Simple method to draw complex figures. If you need antialiasing, use GDIPlus or other advanced graphic means.

```
  procedure DrawCurveArrow(ACanvas: TCanvas; AColor: TColor;
    X0, Y0, Size: Integer);
  const
    Magic = 0.552; // constant to approximate circular arc with Bezier curve
  var
    Pt: array of TPoint;
    Flags: array of Byte;
    R, RMag: Integer;
  begin
    SetLength(Pt, 18);
    SetLength(Flags, 18);
    R := 5 * Size div 16;
    RMag := Round(R * Magic);

    Pt[0] := Point(X0 + 1, Y0); // to thicken tail a bit
    Flags[0] := PT_MOVETO;
    Pt[1] := Point(X0 + 1, Y0 - RMag);
    Flags[1] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[2] := Point(X0 + R - RMag, Y0 - R);
    Flags[2] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[3] := Point(X0 + R, Y0 - R);
    Flags[3] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[4] := Point(X0 + R + RMag, Y0 - R);
    Flags[4] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[5] := Point(X0 + 2 * R, Y0 - RMag);
    Flags[5] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[6] := Point(X0 + 2 * R, Y0);
    Flags[6] := PT_BEZIERTO;

    Pt[7] := Point(X0 + Size div 2, Y0);
    Flags[7] := PT_LINETO;
    Pt[8] := Point(X0 + Size * 3 div 4, Y0 + Size div 4);
    Flags[8] := PT_LINETO;
    Pt[9] := Point(X0 + Size, Y0);
    Flags[9] := PT_LINETO;
    Pt[10] := Point(X0 + 7 * Size div 8, Y0);
    Flags[10] := PT_LINETO;

    R := 7 * Size div 16;
    RMag := Round(R * Magic);
    Pt[11] := Point(X0 + 2 * R, Y0 - RMag);
    Flags[11] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[12] := Point(X0 + R + RMag, Y0 - R);
    Flags[12] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[13] := Point(X0 + R, Y0 - R);
    Flags[13] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[14] := Point(X0 + R - RMag, Y0 - R);
    Flags[14] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[15] := Point(X0, Y0 - RMag);
    Flags[15] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[16] := Point(X0, Y0);
    Flags[16] := PT_BEZIERTO;
    Pt[17] := Point(X0 + 1, Y0);
    Flags[17] := PT_LINETO or PT_CLOSEFIGURE;

    BeginPath(ACanvas.Handle);
    PolyDraw(ACanvas.Handle, Pt[0], Flags[0], Length(Pt));
    EndPath(ACanvas.Handle);
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := AColor;
    FillPath(ACanvas.Handle);
  end;

begin
  DrawCurveArrow(Canvas, clBlue, 100, 200, 300);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that MBo was quicker then me and his solution is better then my. But I'll put my answer anyway. Note that it counts with white background (MBo's solution is background-independent).

```
procedure draw_arrow(canvas: TCanvas; x, y, size: Integer; color: TColor);
begin
  with canvas do
  begin
    Pen.Style:=psClear;
    Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
    Brush.Color:=color;
    Ellipse(x+1, y, x+size+1, y+size);
    Brush.Color:=clWhite;
    Ellipse(x, y+size div 6, x+Round(size/1.5), y+Round(size/1.2));
    Rectangle(x, y+size div 2, x+size+1, y+size);
    Brush.Color:=color;
    Polygon([Point(x+size div 2, y+size div 2), Point(x+size div 2+Round(size/1.5), y+size div 2), Point(x+size-size div 6, y+Round(size/1.2))]);
  end;
end;
```